# create an array of objects from objects javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this objects from google API, if I console.log(ret) I have this:

```
{name:x, stars:5},
{name:y, stars:4},
{name:j, stars: 3}
```

I am getting this result from the following loop:

```
  for (let i = 0; i < fromGoogle.length; i++) {
    let ret = fromGoogle[i];

  }
```

I want to create an Array of Objects like:

```
[{...},{...},{...}]
```

How do I do it?

Thank you, I am new at JS

Comment: *"I have this objects"* **How** do you have them? Individual variables? Please show complete statements, not code fragments.

Comment: Yes please show all code that encapsulates your problem. Show what you have done. If you have them all as variables (say `i`, `j`, and `k`) you can just do `[i, j, k]`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also note that Stack Overflow is a **very** active place. If you post a question (or answer), please *stick around* for a few minutes to address anything that comes up in the comments.

Comment: just added a loop in the post. I am getting this objects from a GOOGLE API call and I want to store them in an Array of Objects

Comment: @Leo — `fromGoogle` appears to **already be** an Array of Objects.

Answer (score 1):

If you have, for instance, objects referenced by individual variables:

```
let a = {name:x, stars:5};
let b = {name:y, stars:4};
let c = {name:j, stars: 3};
```

you can create an array of them using an *array initializer* (aka "array literal"):

```
let array = [a, b, c];
```

You don't need the individual variables, though, you can do this:

```
let array = [
    {name:x, stars:5},
    {name:y, stars:4},
    {name:j, stars: 3}
];
```